# Ajax post form to servlet without refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsp, refresh

I understand that this question has been done to death so I'll apologise in advance but I'm just not getting it. What I am looking to do is some sort of rating system and while I've looked at several examples in tutorials on other sites, they are all a bit bloated and not really what I'm after.

I need to submit a form when a radio button is selected. The radio button represents some number which I need to use server side as I need to update databases etc with this value. What I need after that is for the updated database value to be returned to the jsp and display this number.

All of the backend stuff isn't a problem really. All I need is to be able to send the form data to the servlet and get the updated value back without reloading the page. I  would also like to use a `post` `form` action to do this if possible, but that isn't crucial.

**Skip to edit 3**

Is this possible without having some 200 line JQuery / Ajax script ?

I've gotten as far as

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/Rating',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        message: s
    },
    success: 
        function(msg){
            alert("Success");
            // ill want to do something with divs here later i.e a refresh or toggle
        }                   
    });
});
```

which I gleamed from other threads on this topic. I need it to work with some basic html form like

```
<form action="/" id="rating" method="Post">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction">
</form>
```

Edit: The servlet i want to send the information to is named Rating with a url-pattern /Rating in my web.xml file. Do i get the information passed to it with a standard request.getAttribute(String value) call and which string value do i look for? "message" or "s" ?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Edit 2:** I set up a test page to try to make this ajax stuff work. Using 3nigma's solution i have

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(":radio").change(function(){

var formData = $("form").serialize();
console.log(formData);
$.post("/Test",{data:formData},function(val){
//val has the updated value that you will send from the servlet
//do something
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="/Test" id="rating" method="Post">
<input type="radio" name="ra1" />
<input type="radio" name="ra1" />
<input type="radio" name="ra1" />
<input type="radio" name="ra1" />
<input type="radio" name="ra1" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

inside my Test servlet in the doPost method i have

```
request.getAttribute("formData");
request.getAttribute("data");
System.out.println("test");
```

when i run the jsp page and select a radio button nothing appears to happen. The System.out.println() doesnt get executed which makes me think that its never reaching the servlet.
Anybody see anything im doing wrong ?

**Edit 3**
Finally got it working. I'll include the problems i had incase anybody gets stuck in some of the same places.

When sending to the servlet with name Rating the url is just "Rating" and not "/Rating" as it may be in web.xml.

Inside the doPost method in Servlet, use request.getParameter("itemID") to retrieve the data

The best thing i did all weekend was install firebug. That pretty much told me where i failed and set me on the right track. Thanks to the people who replied.

The code I ended up using was posted by danniehansenweb except I fixed a simple mistake. The comma inside the data { } should not be there. Instead move it outside the closing curly bracket like

```
data {itemID : rel },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the .click event for the radio buttons.

Such example could look likethis:

**HTML**

```
   <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="1" />
   <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="2" />
   <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="3" />
   <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="4" />
   <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="5" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.doAction').click(function () {
        var rel = parseInt($('.doAction:checked').attr('rel'));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                itemID: rel
            }
            url: '/ajax.php',
            success: function (data) {
                if(!data.answer) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This would give each radio button a unique id set in the rel attribute. Then it will when the radio button is clicked send a ajax request to ajax.php as a POST. The data will contain what radio button is currently selected.

Then all you have to do is in your backend handle the request and update the rows out from what is selected.

Comment: Is there a way to send the data directly to a servlet ? or do i need to use some secondary script to handle the data and send it on to servlet then have the servlet respond to the secondary script and the secondary script respond back to the page ? hope that makes sense

Comment: Isn't what you're trying to do is save the settings in a database of some sort? If so then if you uses php just make a PHP file that you send the request to and then save the data there. But what do you mean by a servlet, what i thought you meant was a backend script :)

Comment: im using jsp / java. The servlet has methods like doGet and doPost which take as parameters a HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. So inside this servlet I wanted to use the request.getAttribute("name of object passed by post") to obtain the value and then update the database. I'd then get the new database value and pass it back to the ajax function using either a dispatcher or response.sendRedirect() or something. Ive never used any JQuery before and im equally new to php so if it was possible to avoid php scripts i'd like to head in that direction

Comment: Well if you can make your Java program listen on a port for the http protocol. Then you could send the ajax to "IP:PORT" and then just catch the request in Java. Not sure if it's possible to to listen on a http protocol but give it a try :) If it doesn't seem to work try looking at node.js - With that you could have a serversice JavaScript listener waiting for a request. Once getting it it could send it onto your Java application.

Answer (score 1):

> All i need is to be able to send the form data to the servlet and get the updated value back

remove the onclick handlers

```
<form action="/" id="rating" method="Post">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" />
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" />
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" />
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" />
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" />
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

serialize the form and send it to the servlet

```
$("#btn").click(function(){

var formData = $("form").serialize();
 $.post("/",{data:formData},function(val){
  //val has the updated value that you will send from the servlet
  //do something
  });
});
```

here is hoe the serialized data will look like http://jsfiddle.net/VMgxY/

Comment: from a style point of view i was kind of hoping to avoid the use of a submit button. If I have a servlet named Rating.java which has a url-pattern in the web.xml file of /Rating does the "/" in the post call just change to /Rating? and is the value of data retrieved by request.getAttribute("data"); ? Thanks

Comment: have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VMgxY/3/ this uses the change event handler, and yes replace the `/` with the `Rating.java` or what ever path you have specified... the data part i could get it

Comment: Tried your code out and cant get it to work. I updated main post about it. Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/" id="rating" method="Post">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction()" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction()" value="2">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction()" value="3">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction()" value="4">
   <input type="radio" name="ra1" onclick="formaction()" value="5">
</form>
```

note the change in adding `()` to form action, and value attribute, that will differentiate each values.

On every click, the `formaction()` should contain your ajax code.

```
function formaction()
{
     var rating =  $(this).val(); //This captures the radio button's value, which ever clicked
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Test',
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            message: rating
        },
        success: 
            function(msg){
                // msg is the response you got from the server!
                alert("Email Sent");
            }                   
        });
    });
}
```